# Unable to Connect to Chrome in Docker Container with Debugging Port

Tags: python, docker, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Docker container with Chrome installed, and I've exposed the debugging port 9222. The Dockerfile snippet is as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu
ENV USER=root
ENV PASSWORD=password
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 
ENV DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true
RUN apt-get update && \
    echo "tzdata tzdata/Areas select America" > ~/tx.txt && \
    echo "tzdata tzdata/Zones/America select New York" >> ~/tx.txt && \
    debconf-set-selections ~/tx.txt && \
    apt-get install -y abiword gnupg apt-transport-https wget software-properties-common ratpoison novnc websockify libxv1 libglu1-mesa xauth x11-utils xorg tightvncserver && \
    wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualgl/files/2.6.3/virtualgl_2.6.3_amd64.deb && \
    wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/turbovnc/files/2.2.4/turbovnc_2.2.4_amd64.deb && \
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i virtualgl_*.deb && \
    dpkg -i turbovnc_*.deb && \
    mkdir ~/.vnc/ && \
    mkdir ~/.dosbox && \
    echo $PASSWORD | vncpasswd -f > ~/.vnc/passwd && \
    chmod 0600 ~/.vnc/passwd && \
    echo "set border 1" > ~/.ratpoisonrc  && \
    echo "exec google-chrome --no-sandbox --remote-debugging-port=9222 https://google.com">> ~/.ratpoisonrc && \
    openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ~/novnc.pem -out ~/novnc.pem -days 3650 -subj "/C=US/ST=NY/L=NY/O=NY/OU=NY/CN=NY emailAddress=email@example.com"
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 9222
CMD /opt/TurboVNC/bin/vncserver && websockify -D --web=/usr/share/novnc/ --cert=~/novnc.pem 80 localhost:5901 && tail -f /dev/null
```

Here is the relevant Python code snippet:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

current_directory = os.getcwd()
chromedriver_path = os.path.join(current_directory, "chromedriver.exe")
service = Service(executable_path=chromedriver_path)

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", f"localhost:9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get("https://www.google.de/")

# Just for demonstration
time.sleep(10)

# Cleanup and close the browser instance
driver.quit()
```

I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue and establishing a successful connection to Chrome within the Docker container. As you can see, everything is hosted on my local machine. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

When I attempt to connect to it, I encounter the following error in my Python code using Selenium:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:9222 from chrome not reachable
```

I start docker like this:

```
docker run -p 8082:80 -p 9222:9222 chrome-browser
```